# separate shapes in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Newbie to illustrator here and haven't found an answer to this online yet.
Looking to separate all shapes in this vector but cant dissect the circles with scissor tool because of paths placed in circles. I want to move, fill, or transform pieces separately.
[image: Illustrator sample]

Edit: sorry for forgetting the upload!

Comment: We can only guess if you dont provide an image or some actual data to work on. Check that object is not a group or compound path.

Comment: I dont have the option to ungroup or release compound path on these objects. I guess that means it isnt either a group nor a compound path? -Thank you for your comment

Comment: Possibly relevant information: I used eclipse tool to make circles, Pen tool to add the separating lines.

Answer (score 1):

- Select All
- Grab the **Live Paint Bucket** tool
- Pick a color from Swatches
- Start Clicking

Answer (score 0):

Given what you already have there the Shapebuilder tool can get you what you want.

You will need to Select each circle and pen path separately (otherwise the circle overlaps will cause you trouble).

Use the shapebuilder tool to make each circle/ pen tool path into separate shapes.

Then Select and color them as you like

[image]

With the Shapebuilder Tool selected you can quickly toggle to the Selection Tool by holding the cmd/ alt key- upon release of cmd/ alt key you will still be in the Shapebuilder tool.